# Nested Object Insert takes time -Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I involved in the project where I need to persist nested object in a single transaction.

```
class PurchaseOrder{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = PurchaseOrderMaterial.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchaseOrder_id")
    private List<PurchaseOrderMaterial> purchaseOrderMaterials;
    ......
    ......
}
```

And PurchaseOrderMaterial.java

```
class PurchaseOrderMaterial{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = PurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTax.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchaseOrderMaterial_id", nullable = true)
    private List<PurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTax> purchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchaseOrderMaterial_id")
    private List<PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem> purchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItems;
.....
.....
}
```

Other two entities (PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem.java & PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem.java) will not have sub-entity/relations. I framed object from front end. In my service implementation I only called

```
repo.save(purchaseOrder);
```

My application took 5 seconds to store the data.
PS: above code is sample actual code may have more sub entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping has some serious issues. That is why Hibernate is running many update query too. I have tested with the following code. For the seven object it is running seven insert into statement and six update query.

```
    PurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTax purchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes = new PurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTax();
    PurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTax purchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes1 = new PurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTax();

    PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem purchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem = new PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem();
    PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem purchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem1 = new PurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem();

    PurchaseOrderMaterial purchaseOrderMaterials = new PurchaseOrderMaterial();
    purchaseOrderMaterials.setPurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes(Arrays.asList(purchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes, purchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes1));
    purchaseOrderMaterials.setPurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItems(Arrays.asList(purchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem, purchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem1));

    PurchaseOrderMaterial purchaseOrderMaterials1 = new PurchaseOrderMaterial();
    purchaseOrderMaterials.setPurchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes(Arrays.asList(purchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes, purchaseOrderMaterialDutiesAndTaxes1));
    purchaseOrderMaterials.setPurchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItems(Arrays.asList(purchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem, purchaseOrderOtherExpenditureItem1));

    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder();
    purchaseOrder.setPurchaseOrderMaterials(Arrays.asList(purchaseOrderMaterials, purchaseOrderMaterials1));
```

You should change the one-to-many mapping owner side. Please see the following blog https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/